# Prove recurrence relation by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction, recurrence-relations

Never seen this type of recurrence relation before. I need to prove it using induction.

\begin{aligned}u_{1}=3,u_{2}=5,u_{n}=3u_{n-1}-2u_{n-2},n\in \mathbb{N} ,n\geq 3.
\end{aligned}

Prove $u_{n} = 2^k+1$

This is what I did:

#### Basis step

\begin{aligned}
P\left( 3\right) :3\cdot 5-2\cdot 3=9\\
\end{aligned}

#### Inductive step

\begin{aligned}
P\left( k\right) :3u_{k-1}-2u_{k-2}=2^{k}+1\\
P\left( k+1\right) :3u_{k}-2u_{k-1}=2^{k+1}+1
\end{aligned}

If I replace $u_{k}$ in $3u_{k}$, still need to solve $2u_{k-1}$

Two questions:

- How can I use my hypothesis to prove $P(k + 1)$ ?
- What's the name of this type of relation where it depends on two previous results?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: What is $3(2^k+1)-2(2^{k-1}+1)?$

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it but how do you know $u_{k-1}=2^{k-1}+1$ ? I am only given $u_{n}$. I do not know nothing about the behaviour of $u_{n}$ with n < k. But probably, I am wrong.

Comment: @F.Zer This is actually a profound observation.  This is the difference between "strong induction" and "weak induction."  The bottom-line answer is that when performing a proof by induction, after proving your base case you are entitled to assume that your proposition for *all* $k \lt n$, not merely $n-1$.  Do you see why that's true?

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks for your comment. Can't see why is that true. Could you explain ?

Comment: Because the way you proved that your statement is true for, say, $n=37$ is by proving it, inductive step by inductive step, for each $n$ from $1$ through $36$.  Another way to look at a proof by induction that's sometimes fruitful is to assume toward a contradiction that the proposition is false for some $n$.  Any nonempty set of natural numbers must have a smallest element, so consider the smallest $n$ for which the proposition fails.  That means (the inductive step) you can assume that the proposition is true for all $k \lt n$.  Then prove the proposition was true for $n$ after all.

Comment: I am assuming it is true for n = k, but only proved P(3) holds (Base step). Why do you say "the way you proved" ?

Answer (score 3):

Your base case should be:

$u_1 = 3 = 2^1+1\\u_2 = 5 = 2^2+1$

In your inductive step you then assume that $u_k = 2^k+1$ and $u_{k-1} = 2^{k-1}+1$ and you need to show that with this assumption then $u_{k+1} = 2^{k+1}+1$.

You know that

$u_{k+1} = 3u_k - 2u_{k-1} = 3(2^k+1) - 2(2^{k-1}+1)$

so you just have to simplify the expression on the right hand side.

Comment: Thank you. Don't you think my base case should be for n = 3? What do you think ?

Comment: Since $u_k$ depends on the two previous terms in the sequence you need two terms to start the induction. You might as well use the two terms that you are given.